# Need to count in R # of pre-specified words in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to count how many times the following words\phrases appear in a column:

1. home
2. grand slam
3. scores

**Here is the input in row form:**

```
[1] "Ian Desmond hits an inside-the-park home run (8) on a line drive down the right-field line. Brendan Rodgers scores. Tony Wolters scores."
[2] "Ian Desmond lines out sharply to center fielder Jason Heyward."                                                                          
[3] "Ian Desmond hits a grand slam (9) to right center field. Charlie Blackmon scores. Trevor Story scores. David Dahl scores."               
[4] "Ian Desmond homers (12) on a fly ball to center field. Daniel Murphy scores."
```

**Desired output**
The main output I need is a count of how many matches were found. For example, in the input rows there are nine matches.

**Code I tried to use**

```
text <- c("Ian Desmond hits an inside-the-park home run (8) on a line drive down the right-field line. Brendan Rodgers scores. Tony Wolters scores." , "Ian Desmond lines out sharply to center fielder Jason Heyward.", "Ian Desmond hits a grand slam (9) to right center field. Charlie Blackmon scores. Trevor Story scores. David Dahl scores.", "Ian Desmond homers (12) on a fly ball to center field. Daniel Murphy scores.")

df <- data.frame(text, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(text, "scores|grand slam|home")) %>%
  count()
```

1. I have reviewed "solutions" that stackoverflow presented, but could not find one that matched my need.
2. I want to count all occurrences of "scores," "grand slam", and "home" in all the rows of the **text** vector.
3. I would prefer a dplyr solution; however, I am open to other ways of doing it.
4. For the result, I just want the count. In the supplied input, the to-be-counted words\phrases occur nine times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you counting `"homers"` as match to `"home"` ?

You can use `str_count` by pasting the words as one pattern.

```
library(stringr)
words <- c('home', 'grand slam', 'scores')
str_count(df$text, str_c(words, collapse = '|'))
#[1] 3 0 4 2
```

This counts for each `text` how many times the pattern (`str_c(words, collapse = '|')`) appears. To get total number we can `sum` them.

```
sum(str_count(df$text, str_c(words, collapse = '|')))
#[1] 9
```

---

If you want to write a pattern in such a way that `"homers"` do not match to `"home"` you can use word boundaries around the pattern (`\\b`).

```
str_count(df$text, str_c('\\b', words, '\\b', collapse = '|')) 
#[1] 3 0 4 1
```

whose `sum` will give you count as 8.

Comment: Yes, I am counting "homers" as a match to "home".

Comment: Then the first part does what you want. You don't need word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner solution using `str_extract_all` from the package `stringr`:

```
length(unlist(str_extract_all(x, paste0(c('home','grand slam','scores'), collapse = '|'))))
[1] 9
```

Data:

```
x <- c("Ian Desmond hits an inside-the-park home run (8) on a line drive down the right-field line. Brendan Rodgers scores. Tony Wolters scores.",
       "Ian Desmond lines out sharply to center fielder Jason Heyward.",                                                                          
       "Ian Desmond hits a grand slam (9) to right center field. Charlie Blackmon scores. Trevor Story scores. David Dahl scores.",               
       "Ian Desmond homers (12) on a fly ball to center field. Daniel Murphy scores.")
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map_dfc(c("score", "grand slam", "home"), ~ 
    lengths(str_extract_all(df$text, .x))) %>%
     set_names(c("score", "grand slam", "home"))%>%
     mutate(Total = sum(score + `grand slam` + home))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  score `grand slam`  home Total
#  <int>        <int> <int> <int>
#1     2            0     1     9
#2     0            0     0     9
#3     3            1     0     9
#4     1            0     1     9
```

---

If it is the total count

```
map(c("score", "grand slam", "home"), ~ 
    lengths(str_extract_all(df$text, .x))) %>% 
      reduce(`+`) %>%
      sum
#[1] 9
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sum(lengths(Filter(function(x) all(x > 1), 
        gregexpr("score|grand slam|home", df$text))))
#[1] 9
```

Comment: I need the total number of matches (9) shown too.  In the actual dataset there are more than 1,800 rows.

Comment: What does the tilde and `.x` do in the code below "If it is the total count"?

Comment: @Metsfan It is looping over the vector (assuming there are  > 100 words), then the `~` is for anonymous function call `function(x)` .

Comment: @Metsfan Can you please update your post with expected output as it is still not clear to me about the format you wanted